# how to autoload emacs mode if folder contains specific file?

Tags: projectile, minor-mode

I'm writing a custom build mode (mybuild-mode) for custom build tool and want  that mode to be autoloaded in case I'm in the folder which contains `mybuild.sh` file. Also my mode depends on projectile (so the directory should contain the `.projectile` file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `mybuild-mode` is actually a minor mode that should be loaded additionally to the major mode for your source files.

In this case you can use `find-file-hook` to activate that minor mode depending on the presence of `mybuild.sh`:

```el
(define-minor-mode mybuild-mode
  "Mode activated if mybuild.sh file is present in the same directory."
  :lighter " ⚒"
  (if mybuild-mode
      (message "Doing some stuff at start-up.")
    (message "Doing some stuff at shutting-down.")))

(defun mybuild-start-maybe ()
  "Starts mybuild-mode if mybuild.sh is present in `default-directory'."
  (when (file-readable-p "mybuild.sh")
    (mybuild-mode t)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'mybuild-start-maybe)
```

Comment: In my case, due to I use projectile - `(projectile-verify-file "mybuild.sh")`